# Transcompiling to another language

Tags: c, compiler-construction

What are the typical ways in which code can be transcompiled? Currently, I'm writing a simple programming language, and the way it's handled is recursively. A list of nodes are looped through, and say the current node is a variable node, it will call a `emit_variable_node` function, which will literally append some code to a string, for example:

The following code is psuedo-ish, I'm writing my project in C, and compiling to C.

```
char *file_contents;

void emit_variable_node(VariableNode *var) {
    // I know += doesn't work on strings, just pretend it does.
    file_contents += var.getType();
    file_contents += " "; // a space
    file_contents += var.getName();
    // etc
}
```

I'm also assuming that the code we're given has been semantically analyzed, and is correct. The file_contents string is then stored into a temporary file, which is deleted after it's been compiled by a C compiler.

Is that a bad practice, or are there better, more cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Give it a try and see how it looks when you're done :) Depending on the complexity of the transformations, you might find use for some kind of templating library.

Comment: Ahh, it's already partially implemented! I just wanted to check it's an okay implementation before I work on it any further :)

Comment: Hmm I've sadly never done something like this before, but for string parsing I'd use a language like perl or python...but if C++ works, why not. There are some tools out there that might help, for example Bison, Flex or LLVM

Comment: @feliks: Since C lacks convenient string handling functions and I'm used to using printf formats, I tend to use a little library I wrote. IMHO the most of these is `concatf`, which you can extract from [this little bison example](https://github.com/ricilake/barbaric/blob/master/barbaric.y) if you want it.

Comment: Relevant link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler (for those who aren't sure what "transcompiling" means).

Comment: Readers: If you like this question, click "reopen"

Comment: ...OP notes "perfect answer". Hardly too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a parser by any means you like, and generate code as it parses, no AST nodes necessary ("syntax directed translation").  That will generally produce pretty awful code, because the code generator has no opportunity to take context into account to generate better code.

You can build a parser that builds abstract syntax trees (ASTs) as a first pass, and then as a second pass walks over the tree generating code without looking at any neighboring nodes.  This is just the previous answer with ASTs in it.
Here's a [stunningly bad example of unoptimized transpiler output](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Services/EraneaNACA.html) done doing something like this.

Better is to generate code from the AST, where each AST node local code generator inspects its neighbors, to decide what to do.  This will give you somewhat better code.

A better solution is to follow the lead of conventional compilers, build a good front end for your language, including symbol tables and control and data flow analysis.  You can then use this to generate much better code.

Regarding actual code generation: yes, you can print text strings.  String templates are a little more convenient, but they are just a fancy way to print text strings, so they don't add any power or improve the resulting code quality.

A better solution is to transform ASTs in your source language, into ASTs in your target language, including all the local checks and using information from the symbol table and flow analysis.  The nice consequence of this is that by producing ASTs in the target language, you can now apply optimizations in the target language that are not possible in the source language.  [Real compilers do something like this, the but terms they use are "translate AST to IR (internal representation)" and they do optimizations on the IR.]  After all the optimizations on the target AST are complete, you have to pretty-print the final AST... using something like string templates.

Most people don't have the energy to build a good transpiler from scratch.  So they do some hacky thing like the first suggestion (just sayin').   But if you want a really good foundation for transforming code from one language to another, check out our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).   DMS has parsers for many languages, can implement parsers for custom languages, automatically builds ASTs, provides a lot of support for [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html), e.g., building symbol tables and flow analysis, does AST to AST transformation, and has pretty printers. [DMS is designed to be a platform to support this kind of task](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Services/NorthropGrummanB2.html). What this means is you can concentrate on building the high-quality translation part of the task, rather than trying to build all that useful infrastructure.

Comment: This is perfect, thankyou! Kind of irrelevant, Nim compiles to C, what method do they use to do so?

Comment: @feliks:  ... well now I do.  GIYF.  See this document about the Nim compiler: http://nim-lang.org/intern.html   It appears they parse to ASTs.  Because Nim compiles "globally", they build trees for the whole program *first*, do name resolution on a program after *everything* is read, and then apparantly do a lot of tree rewriting.  Reading between the lines, there seems to be some pretty sophisticated algorithms involved in analysis and code generation (certainly consistent with my remarks in "LifeAfterParsing").  In particular, it does not appear that Nim has a trivial code generator.

Comment: @feliks:  ... it helps to know that the guy who developed it appears to have been working on this for ~~ 10 years, and the Github footprints suggests he has 100+ helper developers.   This isn't a "hacky" solution.

Comment: Oh wow, cheers for looking into this for me. I'll have a little study on how their compiler, I'm sure there's a lot I can learn from it. Thanks again :0

Comment: Well, thanks for piquing my curiousity.  Even old farts still 'want to know". I doubt its a "little" study, its a pretty big program. (Most [trans]compilers are).  I dug into it out of interest, but still spent an hour or two to draw the conclusions I did, and I looked at zero source code :-)

Comment: Would a `bad example of unoptimized output` be a good result, then? :D