# Source to source translation in Antlr4

Tags: javascript, parsing, plsql, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to translate PLSQL code to JavaScript code.
I'm using Antlr4 with this grammar: https://github.com/developeron29/PLSQLParser.

I've used the listener to translate pieces of code, something like this:

```
@Override
public void enterBody(BodyContext ctx) {
    functionBody += "function " + funcName + "{\n;
}

@Override
public void exitBody(BodyContext ctx) {
    functionBody += "}\n;
}

...
```

It is working pretty good but the code is growing fast and it is becoming unmaintainable.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this kind of translation?

Comment: PL/SQL -> JavaScript? Above looks neither like JavaScript nor PL/SQL. Can you show what your input and output is so far?

Comment: Translation of one language to another is actually pretty hard if you do it well.  Normally you need a lot more than "just a parser". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28970385/120163

Comment: Why would you want to translate PLSQL to JavaScript?

Comment: @hol, the code above is not the input/output. It is the Listener (in Java) that try to write the javascript code from the parsed tree.

Comment: @IraBaxter, thank you for the link. We are migrating a legacy software in a web based application and we are trying to automate a part of the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ANTLR-Listener approach is fine if you can translate the language elements one by one.

Alternatively you can consider the ANTLR-Visitor approach. I think is is suitable if you expect several compiler passes with different parse tree traversal Strategies, or different intermediate results:

- code for one node must not be split between enter and exit
- you can prune the parse tree or even construct an AST (the AST-Builder would be a Visitor)
- You can easily delegate the evaluation of nodes to other parse tree visitors